# Wordpress menu - ajax loading

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Is it possible to dynamically load Wordpress menu via Ajax?

Best solution would be using wp_nav_menu().

Answer (score 1):

**If your theme needs to dynamically initialize menus with JavaScript, the pattern for the initialization code should be:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function initMainNavigation( container ) {
        /* set up container... */
    }
    initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );

    $( document ).on( 'customize-preview-menu-refreshed', function( e, params ) {
        if ( 'primary' === params.wpNavMenuArgs.theme_location ) {
            initMainNavigation( params.newContainer );
            /* optionally sync a previous menu state from params.oldContainer... */
        }
    });
});
```

The params being passed to the event handler consists of the following properties:

- **newContainer:** jQuery object containing the new menu container element retrieved from Ajax; this is what you would manipulate to initialize.
- **oldContainer:** the previous jQuery object holding the element for the replaced menu container; this is useful if there is any state in the old menu that should persist in the new menu, such as which submenus are expanded (as in Twenty Fifteen).
- **wpNavMenuArgs:** The array of arguments passed to `wp_nav_menu()` in the template, such as template_location.
- **instanceNumber:** The index for which `wp_nav_menu()` call being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom file to handle ajax requests in your theme, returning the HTML output of `wp_nav_menu();` and call that file.

wp-content/themes/your-theme/ajax.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

It's simple, but efficient. Be careful with security though. Make sure to validate input and dont `eval()` any input!